# Testing Insert All Oracle query with HSQL DB

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, hsqldb

I have a query on deciding how I should approach the problem below.
I got a query which tries to insert multiple rows into oracle db table, using an INSERT ALL INTO statement. (and this syntax is specific to ORACLE). But we use hsqldb as in memory DB for our test cases. (in test profile only)
The issue is HSQL DB will not accept the INSERT ALL INTO sql syntax. So we have to either skip test cases for this method, or write a query which inserts single records and invoke the query using a java for loop. Can someone please advice on what would be the best approach? I am assuming that there will not be a severe performance hit on invoking the insert from a java for loop as the loop will not be  having more than approximately 20-30 iterations. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle INSERT ALL allows multi-row inserts into single or multiple tables.

HSQLDB allows multiple row inserts into the same table using this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO t (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
  ('val1_1', 'val1_2', 'val1_3'),
  ('val2_1', 'val2_2', 'val2_3'),
  ('val3_1', 'val3_2', 'val3_3')
```